# why background-image don't work in div (in bootstrap theme)

Tags: html, css

why background-image Don't work in div with class .milad 
(i use bootstrap 4.3)

```css
.milad {
    width: 120px;
    background-image: image-url('Untitled.png');
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="milad"> </div>
```

Comment: Use `background-image: url('Untitled.png');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your CSS property is wrong it should be `url`

example:

```css
.milad {
    width: 200px;
    /*put path of your image file in the url */
    /*background-image: url('Untitled.png'); */
    background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/grayscale');
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="milad"> </div>
```

Comment: tanx but i want use image in theme folder and image name is (Untitled.png) How to do it؟

Comment: updated the code

Comment: when i use internet url its work and image be seen but when use local url like you said didnt work

Comment: is your image path right, is it in the same folder as the CSS file?  If it is in the same folder try using ```'./Untitled.png'```

Comment: yes it is same folder , please see this photo (https://imgur.com/a/M5QN0zH)

Comment: your css code is in css folder use ```'./../Untitled.png'```

Comment: Thank you fixed :))